# Skype not notify of new messages until it is opened

Tags: samsung, skype

My Skype is not showing new messages or Skype call until I open it.

I have a Samsung J6+. It night be my fault due to changing many settings at once now causing Skype to behave this way. So it was with other chat messengers such as Wire and Whatsapp.

But I got Whatsapp working fine now, when i disable "data saver" feature under "data usage".

However Skype and Wire are not working as they should.

Can anybody please help by provide a list of possible settings and solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you exempted them from battery optimization? Check the battery settings for these two apps, exempt them, and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: i seached my phone setting area.. can't locate "battery optimization" setting. i saw that before, but i just can't find it now.

Comment: Go to System settings->Battery. Then tap on the 3-dot icon on the title bar, or press the menu button on your device. A drop-down menu will appear. There you can find a link for battery optimization.